# Filter method getting rid of all items after filter

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistadapter

I'm using a custom ExpandableListViewAdapter with my code. When I filter the code with respect to the user input the app works fine. However when the user erases said input the list view leaves the last search and then goes blank when an input is put in. Here is my code:
Main:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Net;
using Java.Lang;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using Java.Util;
using System.Threading;
using Org.Json;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RestSharp.Extensions.MonoHttp;
using Android.Text;

namespace DictionaryE
{
[Activity(Label = "DictionaryE", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/logo")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
private ExpandableListView list;
private ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;
private int length;
private List<string> group= new List<string>();
private string[] names;
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> Mapout = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
private SearchView searchBar;
private View.IOnClickListener listener;


protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    ActionBar.Hide();
    // Set Views
    searchBar = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchBar);
    list = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.lv);
    //Set Groups
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string json = client.DownloadString("********************");
    JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray(json);
    length = myarray.Length();
    names = new string[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        JSONObject Element = myarray.GetJSONObject(i);
        names[i] = Element.GetString("name");
    }
    setData(out mAdapter);
    list.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.Filter.InvokeFilter();

}

private void setData(out ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter)
{
    string urlholder;
    string url;
    string json;
    string time;
    string timestamp;
    string together;
    WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
    for (int i=0;i < length; i++)
    {
        List<string> listplaceholder = new List<string>();
        group.Add(names[i]);
        urlholder = Uri.EscapeDataString(names[i]);
        url = "**********";
        json = client1.DownloadString(url);
        JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray(json);
        int length2 = array2.Length();
        for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++)
        {
            JSONObject Element = array2.GetJSONObject(j);
            time=Element.GetString("wait");
            JSONObject TimeElement = array2.GetJSONObject(j);
            timestamp = TimeElement.GetString("created_at");
            timestamp=timestamp.Replace("T", " at ");
            int index = timestamp.IndexOf(".");
            if (index > 0)
            {
                timestamp = timestamp.Substring(0, index);
            }
            together = time + " minutes posted at " + timestamp;
            listplaceholder.Add(together);
        }
        Mapout.Add(group[i], listplaceholder);


    }
    mAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, group, Mapout);
}
private void searchBar_QueryTextChange(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
    {

        mAdapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);
    }

}
}
```

This is my ExpandableListview Adapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;

namespace BarStar
{
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter, IFilterable
{
    private Context context;
    public List<string> listGroup;
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild;

    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> listGroup, Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.listGroup = listGroup;
        this.listChild = listChild;
    }
    public override int GroupCount
    {
        get
        {
            return listGroup.Count;
        }
    }

    public override bool HasStableIds
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Filter Filter => new GroupFilter(this);

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        listChild.TryGetValue(listGroup[groupPosition], out result);
        return result[childPosition];
    }

    public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        listChild.TryGetValue(listGroup[groupPosition], out result);
        return result.Count;
    }

    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Children, null);
        }
        TextView textViewItem = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue);
        string content = (string)GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        textViewItem.Text = content;
        return convertView;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return listGroup[groupPosition];
    }

    public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Groups, null);
        }
        string textGroup = (string)GetGroup(groupPosition);
        TextView textViewGroup = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Header);
        textViewGroup.Text = textGroup;
        return convertView;
    }

    public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }


}
```

}

This is my Filter Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;

namespace BarStar
{
 class GroupFilter : Filter
{
    ExpandableListViewAdapter _adapter;
    ExpandableListViewAdapter placeholder;
    public GroupFilter(ExpandableListViewAdapter adapter)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
    }
    protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
    {
        var returnObject = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.Length() == 0)
        {
            // No filter implemented we return all the list
            returnObject.Values = _adapter;
            returnObject.Count = _adapter.listGroup.Count();
        }
        else
        {

            var tmpList = _adapter.listGroup.Where(g => g.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString().ToLower()));

            returnObject.Values = FromArray(tmpList.ToArray());
            returnObject.Count = tmpList.Count();
        }
        return returnObject;
    }

    protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
    {
        if (results.Count == 0)
        {
            _adapter.NotifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
        else
        {
            _adapter.listGroup = results.Values.ToArray<string>().ToList<string>();
            _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            constraint.Dispose();
            results.Dispose();
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when the user erases said input the list view leaves the last search and then goes blank when an input is put in

You need to do a few changes to `ExpandableListviewAdapter` to let it dynamically changes according to your user input:

In `ExpandableListviewAdapter.cs` create a local variable to store the filter and don't create a new Filter when you call the getter of `Filter`:

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter,IFilterable
{
   private GroupFilter _filter;
   ...
   public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> listGroup, Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.listGroup = listGroup;
        this.listChild = listChild;
        _filter = new GroupFilter(this);
    }
    ...
    public Filter Filter => _filter;
}
```

Then in your `Filter` create a new list to store the original data of your `listGroup`:

```
private class GroupFilter : Filter
{
    List<string> _originalList;
    ...
    public GroupFilter(ExpandableListViewAdapter adapter)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
        _originalList = new List<string>(adapter.listGroup);
    }

    ...
    protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
    {
        var returnObject = new FilterResults();

        //var tmpList= _originalList.Where(g => g.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString().ToLower()));
        //use LinQ to generate the filter result 
        var tmpList = from o in _originalList where o.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString().ToLower()) select o;

        returnObject.Values = FromArray(tmpList.ToArray());
        returnObject.Count = tmpList.Count();
        return returnObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry what do I put in publish results? Because the _originalList does not have NotifyDataSetChanged(); for it

Comment: Publish results stays the same. I've updated the demo, please have a check: [TestFilterDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/TestFilterDemo)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! that TestFilterDemo is a life saver

Comment: Do you have something I can contact you on?

Comment: Sorry, it is against my company's policy to share any private contact.

Comment: That is okay! I just have one last question! Im bad with expandable list views!

Comment: It involves adding different things to the child

Comment: Hey I have posted a new question. Please look at it if you can. Thank you!